# Git Rebase And Work With Single Branch

Tags: git

Our Git admin said there are too many branches to keep track of. So he suggested each of us create just one branch--eg. DG_my_permanent_branch--and rebase the code before pushing it and never delete it. Has anyone tried this before? It looks like what I did with SVN commits.

I am at a loss to understand the commands to use when trying something like this. There is very little room for error and I don't want to annoy the admin. I would appreciate any help in this regard.

Thanks 
murthy

Comment: What a strange idea. Are you sure s/he didn't mean you to create your own **fork**?

Comment: "Too many branches to keep track of" is a symptom of potentially *several* underlying issues.  How are they keeping track of branches?  What dictates the canonical source of truth?

Comment: You could just create as many branches as you want _locally_, and never push them up. Then, rebase your local branch(es) onto `master` when you want to push changes.

Comment: @Makoto That, too. That smells of a systemic organization problem that should be addressed. Many large companies maintain a single repo with thousands or tens-of-thousands of branches with no issue. We do that as well, we have over several thousand feature branches and have never had any problem organizing or cloning the repo.

Comment: Hi @willoller are the steps to do that something like: create DG_my_permanent_branch; make commit; rebase; push DG_my_permanent_branch and repeat this for the life of the project? Basically I want to recycle the DG_my_permanent_branch name WITHOUT creating multiple LOCAL branches. Kindly advise.

Comment: You *can* operate that way if you really want to; it doesn't take advantage of much of what git (or other dvcss) have to offer. But your workflow will technically work.